# dir() without built-in methods

Tags: python

Is there some way to get all of the attributes of an object without the built ins?  I'm hoping to achieve this without the types package or without manually checking for double underscores if possible.

I've tried dir, but it gives me all the built-in stuff.  Ideally i'd like something like

```
class A():
    foo = 'bar'
>>>> dir(a)
['foo']
```

instead of

```
>>>> dir(a)
['__doc__', '__module__', 'foo']
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Do you just want to filter out the "special" methods, or actually know which methods are implemented in the instance itself, not inherited from a base (or both, as these are different questions, really)?

You can filter out the special methods with something reasonably simple like:

```
def vdir(obj):
    return [x for x in dir(obj) if not x.startswith('__')]

>>> vdir(a)
['foo']
```

Comment: Yes, I'm just interested in filtering the special methods. I thought about this, but thought there might something more direct.  The only way to detect these is through string functions?

Comment: "The only way to detect these is through string functions?" Yes, special methods are identical to regular methods, the double-underscore distinction is simply a convention.

Answer (score 1):

I use list(reversed(dir(a))) to first show defined method and attributes rather than showing the built-in methods and attributes first.

Answer (score -1):

I found myself writing code to do that so often that I put it in a small Python package called [apoor](https://pypi.org/project/apoor) with other miscellaneous functions I found myself reusing.

```
>>> from apoor import fdir 
>>> class A: foo = “bar”
>>> fdir(A)
[“foo”]
```