# Click only shows first character of incorrect option name (Error: no such option: )

Tags: python, click, command-line-interface

I am using Click to parse options to a very simple script.

[image]

All my options must be single dash (i.e., -my_arg) as a requirement.

This is my problem:
If a user incorrectly types the argument, (e.g., -my_arf), then click **only shows the first character -m in the error message**:

`Error: no such option: -m`

I *would like* for it to say, for example passing -my_arf:

`Error: no such option: -my_arf`.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe in that case you would have to add the `-m` option yourself and then say that it was an error pointing to `-my_arg`. Maybe take a look at the click documentation on error handling. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39596070/python-click-custom-error-message) may be useful

A (maybe better) way would be to overwrite the error and point the user to the help command.